# How to sub-select rows for equality with float dtype using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

I have the following dataset example.

```
df_csv_y =  pd.read_csv('y_factors.csv')

                 time    value
0       736527.481944  27.20001
1       736527.482639  27.10001
2       736527.483333  27.10001
3       736527.484028  27.10001
4       736527.484722  27.10001
              ......
```

And I tried the index using the code below.

```
df_csv_y[df_csv_y.time== 736527.482639]
```

I indexed the values that existed in the dataset, but the results were as follows.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [time, value]
Index: []
```

I get the result when I retrieve an integer, but I can not retrieve the float data like the time column of the dataset above.

i want to know how solve this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is that your real float values have higher precision than the displayed values, you can use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) and set the tolerance to a higher precision than the default to select values that are close enough:

```
In[165]:
df[np.isclose(df['time'],736527.482639, 0.0000000001)]

Out[165]: 
            time     value
1  736527.482639  27.10001
```

Your current posted sample data works but your real data has higher precision. You can adjust the `atol` param to `np.isclose` to set the absolute tolerance.

The other aspect to this is that comparing float values for equality will tend generally to just not work due to [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) so when dealing with floating point values it's better to use something like `np.isclose` for comparison